# python: open filename with 'ﹺ' character

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

I have a file called `ﹺ$ˊ$if.1.smali`. When I try to open it I get the error:

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename:
>   '?$/\xef$if.1.smali'

I believe they are Chinese characters.

How can I open the file correctly?

i use python 2.7.13, my codepage is windows 1250

Comment: Can you post the line where you're reading the file?

Comment: @sP_ ' for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(file_path):
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.smali'):
                filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
                with open(filepath, 'r') as smali_file:
                    content = smali_file.read()
                    self.countCallFile(content)' where file_path is the path of the file

Comment: Python 2 or 3? What platform are you on? If it's Windows, what's your OEM code page? If it's Linux or anything else, what's your locale?

Comment: Those obviously aren't Chinese characters, but they could be what you get from misreading, say, UTF-8-encoded Chinese characters as if they were cp1252-encoded characters, or maybe even vice-versa.

Comment: @abarnert windows 1250

Comment: You still didn't answer which Python version.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to include the relevant code, and other important pieces of information; don't just put them in comments.

Comment: Anyway, the only thing that can come after `\xef` in UTF-8 is a second-byte character from `\x80` to `\xbf`, not a `$`. And there's nothing that encodes to the byte `$` in windows-1250 besides the character `$`. And `\xef` in Windows-1250 is U+010F, `ď`—that's a `d` with a hacek (used if Czech and a few related languages). So, if this was supposed to be Chinese characters, I think it was already corrupted badly at some earlier step. What makes you think it's Chinese in the first place?

Comment: My file belongs to a set of malware samples I've downloaded, most of the time being Chinese or Russian@abarnert

Comment: Meanwhile, I think the error is about the `?`, not the `\xef`. Do your pathnames actually have `?` in them (in which case the workaround is going to be horrible and painful), or is Python reading the pathnames wrong?

Comment: Also, do you actually need this to be in Python 2.7? There have been a lot of improvements to the way Python deals with screwy filesystems under Windows over the past half-decade or so, but only in Python 3.

Comment: my files contain the '?' character. since I can not find a simple solution I'm thinking of creating a script and renaming all these "bad files".